# Can't see the created table in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to create a table in android studio and when I go to the ADB tool and go to SQLITE3... I can go into  my database but when I write `.tables` from the command line nothing shows up. Here is the code I have for creating my database and it's tables.

```
public class DatabaseOperations extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public static final String NAME = "event_name";
    public static final String LOCATION = "event_location";
    public static final String DATE = "event_date";
    public static final String TIME = "event_time";

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "events_stuff.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "events";
    public static final int database_version = 7;
    public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME+"( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+ NAME + " TEXT,"
            + LOCATION + " TEXT,"+DATE+" TEXT,"+TIME+" TEXT);";

    public DatabaseOperations(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, database_version);
        Log.d("Database operations", "Database created");

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sdb)
    {
        sdb.execSQL(CREATE_QUERY);
        Log.d("Database operations", "Table Created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void addProduct(Events e) {

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(NAME, e.get_eventname());
        values.put(LOCATION, e.get_eventloc());
        values.put(DATE, e.get_eventdate());
        values.put(TIME, e.get_eventdate());
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Then in my fragment... I try inserting information into the table like this:

```
public static EditText eventName;
public static EditText eventLoc;
public static EditText eventDate;
public static EditText eventTime;
public static DatabaseOperations mDBHelper;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    mDBHelper = new DatabaseOperations(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    mDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.save:
            newProduct();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "YAY YOUR EVENT HAS INSERTED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public void newProduct ()
{
    DatabaseOperations dbHandler = new DatabaseOperations(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Events events =
            new Events(eventName.getText().toString(), eventLoc.getText().toString(), eventDate.getText().toString(), eventTime.getText().toString());
    dbHandler.addProduct(events);

}
```

Also my events class is defined as follows:

```
public class Events
{

    private int _id;
    private String _eventname;
    private String _eventloc;
    private String _eventdate;
    private String _eventtime;

    public Events(){}

    public Events(String _eventname, String _eventloc, String _eventdate, String _eventtime)
    {
        this._eventname = _eventname;
        this._eventloc = _eventloc;
        this._eventdate = _eventdate;
        this._eventtime = _eventtime;
    }

    public void set_id(int _id)
    {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    public void set_eventname(String _eventname)
    {
        this._eventname = _eventname;
    }

    public void set_eventloc(String _eventloc)
    {
        this._eventloc = _eventloc;
    }

    public void set_eventdate(String _eventdate)
    {
        this._eventdate = _eventdate;
    }

    public void set_eventtime(String _eventtime)
    {
        this._eventtime = _eventtime;
    }

    public int get_id()
    {
        return _id;
    }

    public String get_eventname()
    {
        return _eventname;
    }

    public String get_eventloc()
    {
        return _eventloc;
    }

    public String get_eventdate()
    {
        return _eventdate;
    }

    public String get_eventtime()
    {
        return _eventtime;
    }


}
```

When I try and insert my data it says it's working but when I go into the command line not even a table is showing up. How do I create a table, and if I already have one created where can I see that information?? I have combed through many youtube videos and stackoverflow posts and none of them have worked.

Thanks!

Comment: What commands do you use on the commandline?

Comment: to see if my table was created.... I entered the adb command: adb pull /sdcard/events_stuff.db and then wrote: sqlite3 events_stuff.db

Comment: `public static EditText` oh boy, memory leak galore

Comment: I'm not too considered on memory leaks... I can worry about that once I can actually see tables lol

Comment: See this library: https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Android-Debug-Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) in DatabaseOperations add method :-

```
public Cursor getAllRows() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    return db.query(TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
}
```

2) In Fragment after **`newProduct()`**;

```
   Cursor csr = mDBHelper.getAllRows();
   Log.d("PRODUCTS","# of Rows=" + Integer.toString(csr.getCount());
   while (csr.moveToNext) {
       Log.d("PRODUCTS",
           "Row=" + csr.getString(1)
       );
   }
   csr.close();
```

This should list the number of rows,  and the NAME (event_name column) of each row, if any to the Log.

Access to see the database may be restricted according to the device being used. It appears though that you can copy the database. What I use is SQliteManager which is a browser extension (there are likely other similar products).

Note I've not tested the above so there may be the odd typo. I've also used, for brevity, the index/offset for the NAME/event_name column. Ideally you'd use the column name to get the index e.g. instead of `"Row=" + csr.getString(1)` it would be better to code

`"Row=" + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseOperations.NAME))`

Comment: Thanks Mike! I will test this shortly

Comment: This is perfect! So to get the rest of my columns into the output I would do the last code snippet that you posted (csr.getString(ccsr.getColumnIndex...))

Comment: @UmdiBarram yep, e.g.`... + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseOperations.LOCATION))` (which is equivalent to `csr.getString(2)`). 0 would be ID (*p.s. it may be beneficial to use _id rather than ID, as CursorAdpaters (such as for ListView) need a column called _id*).